# Tilt View - Steering Wheel-Style

Tags: 3d-view

I'm making some dice in blender and I just want to tilt the view as if I'm turning my head.
I know there used to be a "Roll View" that accomplished this, but what's the simplest way to do this in the current version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The *Track To* constraint to your *Camera* should do the trick

[image]

UPDATE 2022/07/12:

Hope I got it correctly. Place an *Empty* and parent it to the **Die**, while having the Die in the Origin and zero rotation.

Then Add *6 Cameras* for each side of the **Die** *(or just one for the desired side)*

Parent the *Cameras* to the *Empty*

[image]

Then, while moving the **Die** the cameras will move accordingly and you can switch between the *Cameras* with **Ctrl+0**

[image]

You should see the planview of each side of the **Die**

Comment: Doing that seems to rotate the object in the space, not my view of the object.I'm looking to rotate my view, as if I'm turning my head, while the object remains fixed in the space.

Comment: Could you send me a link to a video describing the effect you want to achieve? I thought the dice moves and you want to look it as it moves.

Comment: Simply put, imagine you're looking straight at one face of a die, but the number is pointed towards the wrong direction. I just want to pivot my view so that I'm looking at it straight, with the top of the number towards the top of my screen. I don't want to move the die, I just want to pivot my view. I can click the mouse wheel and turn my view, but it just kind of orbits the object, and doesn't give a clean rotation.

Comment: Check the updated answer and let me know if that was the case.